# Passing row form datagridview form 1 to datagridview form 2

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Form 1

Form 2

How to write the code for:

when click the row at form 1 datagridview,  form 1 will close and and open form 2 with the datagridview together with the row selected in 1 and also send data( shelf/level) to PIC?

Comment: could you explain your question better? do you want to have the same `DataGridView`, duplicated in `Form1` and `Form2`? Or you just want to take the selected row and insert it in a new `DataGridView` control in `Form2`?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. I just want to take the selected row and insert it in a new DataGridView control in Form2.

Comment: And the database i use is SQL Server.

Comment: Oscar, can u help me on it? give me some hint please..i am struggling with it since i am engineering student but need to do this programming stuff...waiting for ur help!!...

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code Try this as per your requirement

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    String str1  = String.Empty
    String str2 = String.Empty

    str1 = this.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    str2 = this.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()

    Form2 f2=new Form2(str1,str2)
    f2.Showdialog()
 }
```

Form2 code

```
 public Form2(string str1,string str2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("C", "C1");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("C","c2");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(str1, str2);
    }
```